# errors when build spark-mllib_2.10

Tags: eclipse, maven, apache-spark, m2eclipse, apache-spark-mllib

I checked out the apache spark project, trying to build the mllib_2.10. However, I got the following error. What have I missed here? Thank you!

[image: enter code here]

[image]

---

I then tried in eclipse: Run as -> Maven build -> goal: package  and get the following error:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "qtp913470727-59183"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "sparkWorker2-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-42"
Exception in thread "qtp913470727-59184" Exception in thread "qtp1386084932-462" Exception in thread "qtp1406684524-398" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "qtp149043988-424"
Exception in thread "qtp1386084932-59186" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "qtp913470727-59184"
Exception in thread "qtp1406684524-397" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "sparkWorker2-scheduler-1"

Exception in thread "qtp1386084932-455" Exception in thread "qtp1406684524-394" Exception in thread "qtp149043988-59182" Exception in thread "qtp913470727-467" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "Timer-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "qtp149043988-419" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "sparkMaster-scheduler-1"
Exception in thread "qtp149043988-418" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "sparkWorker1-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-52"
```

And I already increase the memory in eclipse.ini like below:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
```

Is there a way to get this thing work in eclipse? Thanks!

Comment: Those are not build errors. Those are warnings displayed in M2e. Can you build the application on the command line?

Comment: Yes. Command line build using maven for the entire spark project was successful. But I wanted to play/modify with the source code to do some experiments ... so I need to have the project open properly in eclipse ... is that possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can build it on the command line successfully, it will work in Eclipse with M2Eclipse as well.

Just use Run As - Maven build ...

and configure as desired.

The warnings you see are about the incremental behaviour within Eclipse, but even if they dont fully match and work, you will still be able to build the project.

If you are running out of memory it might be the meory allocated to Maven or Eclipse. Set the memory for Maven with the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried as you suggested, please see the error above. Is there a way to make it work in eclipse? Thanks!